# Electro-Magnet with Long Magnetic Field Range

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

I want a magnet that has a long magnetic range. But I want it to attract in thee direction perpendicular to the range.

[image]

Comment: "Perpendicular to the range"? I don't see much sense in the expression. Do you think that the range is some plane or surface?

Comment: I want a magnet that can attract things from quite far away in comparison to its size. I want to know if there is an electromagnet that does that.